# Stored Procedure - create a cursor - accept an OUT parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, database-cursor

I was hoping to get some help the the below question, unfortunately the script I have created isn't working. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Question:
Write a script that creates a stored procedure named test. This stored procedure should create a cursor for a result set that consists of the product_name and list_price columns for each product with a list price that’s greater than $700. The rows in this result set should be sorted in descending sequence by list price. The stored procedure should accept an OUT  parameter where a message is passed out of the procedure.  Then, the procedure should set the out parameter to a string variable that includes the product_name and list price for each product so it looks something like this:
*Gibson SG*,*2517.00*|*Gibson Les Paul*,*1199.00*|
Here, each value is enclosed in asterisk(*), each column is separated by a     comma (,) and each row is separated by a pipe character (|).

My script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test( OUT message VARCHAR(200) )
BEGIN
DECLARE product_name_var VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE list_price_var DECIMAL(9,2);
DECLARE row_not_found TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE s_var VARCHAR(400) DEFAULT '';

DECLARE invoice_cursor CURSOR for
    SELECT 
        product_name,
        list_price
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        list_price > 700
    ORDER BY list_price DESC;
    
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET row_not_found = TRUE;

OPEN invoice_cursor;

FETCH invoice_cursor INTO product_name_var, list_price_var;
WHILE row_not_found = FALSE DO

SET s_var = CONCAT(s_var,'*', product_name_var,'*,*',list_price_var,'*|');
    FETCH invoice_cursor INTO product_name_var, list_price_var;
END WHILE;

SELECT s_var AS message;
END
```

Comment: Your code may produce incorrect result (may produce NULL whereas the data exists). CONCAT() produces NULL when any argument is NULL. Use nested CONCAT_WS() which ignores NULLs or apply COALESCE() to the columns values. PS. And what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT s_var AS message; - message is seen as an alias

use

```
SET MESSAGE = s_var ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c43887fd68a17e5b1dc2093d10cd03ec

and beware nulls...